# Executing std.process synchronously from vibe.d sometimes silently hangs the server

Tags: d, vibed

I wrote a `vibe.d` web-UI for `clang-format`, when presented with [this input](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/digitalbitbox/mcu/master/tests_unit.c) while using LLVM style, the server hangs.

The code for handling POST:

```
void post(string style, string code)
{
    import std.algorithm;
    import std.file;
    import std.conv;
    import std.process;
    auto pipes = pipeProcess(["clang-format", "-style="~style], Redirect.stdout | Redirect.stdin);
    scope(exit) wait(pipes.pid);

    pipes.stdin.write(code);
    pipes.stdin.close;
    pipes.pid.wait;

    code = pipes.stdout.byLine.joiner.to!string;

    string selectedStyle = style;

    render!("index.dt", styles, code, selectedStyle);
}
```

This probably shouldn't be done in a blocking way, but I am at a loss how to do it asynchronously. I have tried wrapping the contents of the function in `runTask`, but I couldn't figure out a way to call it correctly.

How can I make it reliable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably writing too much data to the program's `stdin` without reading its `stdout`. Since the pipe buffer size is limited, this causes the executed program to block on writing to its `stdout`, which in turn causes your program to block on writing to its `stdin`.

The solution is to read data as you are writing it. A simple way to do it is to create a second thread which reads the data, while the main thread writes it.